# Form a matrix to have inequality elements

Tags: matrix, syntax

It looks like a silly question, but I could not find any answers online. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Say I have two lists now.

```
L1={{k},{2k+1},{3k+3},{4k},{5k-4},{6k}};
L2={">0","<0",">0",">0",">0","<0"}; (*it's in string form, mathematica wont let me run >0 without quotation marks*)
```

and I want to form a matrix like this shown as result (no string form contained)

```
result={{k>0},{2k+1<0},{3k+3>0},{4k>0},{5k-4>0},{6k<0}}
```

so that I can use Reduce to find the range of k for all elements in the result list. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different format from the start to avoid this complication.

```
L1 = {k, 2 k + 1, 3 k + 3, 4 k, 5 k - 4, 6 k};
L2 = {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2};

MapThread[{# > 0, # < 0}[[#2]] &, {L1, L2}]
```

> ```
> {k > 0, 1 + 2 k < 0, 3 + 3 k > 0, 4 k > 0, -4 + 5 k > 0, 6 k < 0}
> ```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Wizard! I will try this as well!

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
L2a = L2 /. {">0" -> (Greater[#, 0] &),  "<0" -> (Less[#, 0] &)}; 

MapThread[Apply, {L2a, L1}]
(*  {k > 0, 1 + 2 k < 0, 3 + 3 k > 0, 4 k > 0, -4 + 5 k > 0, 6 k < 0} *)
```

Or

```
Apply @@@ Thread[{L2a, L1}]
(*  {k > 0, 1 + 2 k < 0, 3 + 3 k > 0, 4 k > 0, -4 + 5 k > 0, 6 k < 0} *)

List /@ Apply @@@ Thread[{L2a, L1}]
(* {{k > 0}, {1 + 2 k < 0}, {3 + 3 k > 0}, {4 k > 0}, {-4 + 5 k >  0}, {6 k < 0}} *)
```

Comment: Congratulations on entering the 60K club! :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, kguler!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
ClearAll[k]
L1 = {{k}, {2 k + 1}, {3 k + 3}, {4 k}, {5 k - 4}, {6 k}};
L2 = {">0", "<0", ">0", ">0", ">0", "<0"};
result = MapThread[{ToExpression@StringJoin[ToString[First@#1], #2]} &, {L1, L2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks Nasser!

Comment: Sorry to bother you. It seems that the code does not work with symbol with subscript. For example, replace k with Subscript[k, 1]. I found this problem because I have all symbols with subscripts. It there a way to work around this? Maybe change the forms